# Deploy Next JS project with asp.net core visual studio react template

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, visual-studio, next.js, server-side-rendering

I decided to add ssr capability with nextjs to the project that started with asp.net core react template in visual studio.
Before adding nextjs when I clicked on the run project button in visual studio both api server and cra server would've started without any problems...but after adding next to my project it gives me a server error.

I fixed that by running `npm run dev` or `npm start` in vs code to start nextjs server alongside visual studio.

And now that I want to publish my project in visual studio there is no clientApp or any other react related folder in my published folder ( and of course it gives internal server error when uploaded to server and looks like it doesn't even build my nextjs app )

How can I publish my nextjs app based on visual studio asp.net core react template?

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to use `nextjs` with `asp.net core`? would you give me a hint if you did (I'll appreciate that).

Comment: Unfortunately, no...after a lot of research I switched to [link](https://reactjs.net/ ) which has ssr capability alongside react @MohammadBarbast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use reverse proxy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#run-the-cra-server-independently

: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Could you explain this to me? I don't understand how to have next.js with asp.net together.

Answer (score 0):

What worked  for me was using the [NextjsStaticHosting-AspNetCore](https://%20NextjsStaticHosting-AspNetCore)
Following the the steps below:

1. Add the package using `dotnet add package NextjsStaticHosting.AspNetCore --version 0.9.2-preview`.
2. Add Next.js hosting support:
   `services.Configure<NextjsStaticHostingOptions(config.GetSection("NextjsStaticHosting")); services.AddNextjsStaticHosting();`
3. Add the following section on appsettings.json:
   `"NextjsStaticHosting": {"RootPath": "client-app"}`
4. Add the following command on package.json
   `"build:export": "npx next build && npx next export -o build/"`
5. Update your build command on your .csproj file to the following:

   `<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:export" />`